# Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never[]'

Tags: angular

I am stuck on a code. Its an online course on Udemy and i run without the movie.title it works. with juts movie.
but whern i want to print the title it gives that error...

And when i run ng serve. i get this.  but in the online video it worked. What am i getting wrong.
Error: src/app/main/movie-list/movie-list.component.html:2:18 - error TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never[]'.

```
 <h3>{{movies.title}}</h3>
               ~~~~~
```

src/app/main/movie-list/movie-list.component.ts:6:16
6   templateUrl: './movie-list.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component MovieListComponent.

Comment: More actual code please

Answer (score 1):

Movies is array and and array has no title.

Next, it should probably be `any` not never (if not even typed Movie DTO interface)

changing declaration to `any` will surely relax compiler, but will not guarantee that everything will work as expected anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to any and it worked.